# Eclipse IDE throws errors for every action

Tags: c++, eclipse, nullpointerexception, ide

I have a few C++ projects I have been working on. I was trying to set some environment variables on OSX. I reverted the changes but am having trouble finding out what is wrong with my IDE. It's throwing errors left and right.

Every time I try to build any program it says:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching Rainstorm".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Does this for all 3 of my projects that were building perfectly before.

Even when I try to clean the projects, it throws an issue saying there were issues during the build. What build? I was cleaning.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
java.lang.NullPointerException encountered while running Rainstorm.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'Superhero'.

java.lang.NullPointerException

java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I can't figure out what is going on here. I tried deleting my workspace and reimporting. No luck. Very frustrating. I've tried restarting as well.